# SQL trigger not working in Azure Elastic DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, scheduled-tasks

I have setup an Elastic Agent from Azure.
The elastic agent uses a db to maintain and work its logic in Azure.
The list of table which it creates is long. But this tables are what I am working on.

1. jobs_internal.job_exectutions (holds each run of the elastic job)
2. dbo.custom_status (table created to track activity of executions)

Table where DML operations will insert to dbo.custom_status schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[custom_status](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [job_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [job_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [job_execution_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [end_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [lifecycle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [column_state] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [entry_time] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.custom_status] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[custom_status] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [entry_time]
GO
```

When I introduce trigger on the jobs_internal.job_executions on AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE

```
CREATE TRIGGER [jobs_internal].[TR_status_message]
ON [jobs_internal].[job_executions]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @activity NVARCHAR(20);

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SET @activity = 'UPDATE';

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[custom_status]
                ([job_id]
               ,[job_name]
               ,[job_execution_id]
               ,[start_time]
               ,[end_time]
               ,[lifecycle]
               ,[message]
               ,[exception]
               ,[column_state])
            SELECT
                org_job_exe.[job_id]
                ,(SELECT name
                FROM jobs_internal.jobs
                WHERE job_id = org_job_exe.job_id)
                ,org_job_exe.[job_execution_id]
                ,org_job_exe.[start_time]
                ,org_job_exe.[end_time]
                ,org_job_exe.[lifecycle]
                ,(SELECT message
                FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
                WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
                ,(SELECT exception
                FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
                WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
                ,@activity
            FROM INSERTED as org_job_exe;

            PRINT 'UPDATE operation failed in custom message trigger';
        END;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
        BEGIN
            SET @activity = 'DELETE';

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[custom_status]
                ([job_id]
               ,[job_name]
               ,[job_execution_id]
               ,[start_time]
               ,[end_time]
               ,[lifecycle]
               ,[message]
               ,[exception]
               ,[column_state])
            SELECT
                org_job_exe.[job_id]
                ,(SELECT name
                FROM jobs_internal.jobs
                WHERE job_id = org_job_exe.job_id)
                ,org_job_exe.[job_execution_id]
                ,org_job_exe.[start_time]
                ,org_job_exe.[end_time]
                ,org_job_exe.[lifecycle]
                ,(SELECT message
                FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
                WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
                ,(SELECT exception
                FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
                WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
                ,@activity
            FROM DELETED as org_job_exe;

            PRINT 'DELETE operation failed in custom message trigger';
        END;

        BEGIN
            SET @activity = 'INSERT';

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[custom_status]
                    ([job_id]
                   ,[job_name]
                   ,[job_execution_id]
                   ,[start_time]
                   ,[end_time]
                   ,[lifecycle]
                   ,[message]
                   ,[exception]
                   ,[column_state])
                SELECT
                    org_job_exe.[job_id],
                    'test'
                    --,(SELECT name
                    --FROM jobs_internal.jobs
                    --WHERE job_id = org_job_exe.job_id)
                    ,org_job_exe.[job_execution_id]
                    ,org_job_exe.[start_time]
                    ,org_job_exe.[end_time]
                    ,org_job_exe.[lifecycle]
                    ,'test'
                    --,(SELECT message
                    --FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
                    --WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
                    ,'test'
                    ,@activity
                FROM INSERTED as org_job_exe;

            PRINT 'INSERT operation failed in custom message trigger';
        END;
    
        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Custom message trigger failed';
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
```

The trigger works but stops all the other CRUD operations/ DML operations on the base table stops causing the elastic jobs to not work and pile up in the queue.

There is already trigger created by ElasticJob server on this table and that is not stopping DML operations for the table

---

Hence, I tried it on a view

jobs.job_executions with DML of INSTEAD OF

```
ALTER TRIGGER [jobs].[TR_job_alert]
ON  [jobs].[job_executions]
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS
        BEGIN
            --just to test normal is being triggered
            insert custom_status
            values (NEWID(), 
            'testing', 
            NEWID(), 
            null, 
            null, 
            'test', 
            null, 
            null, 
            'test', 
            GETDATE());

            --INSERT INTO [dbo].[custom_status]
            --  ([job_id]
            --   ,[job_name]
            --   ,[job_execution_id]
            --   ,[start_time]
            --   ,[end_time]
            --   ,[lifecycle]
            --   ,[message]
            --   ,[exception]
            --   ,[column_state])
            --SELECT
            --  org_job_exe.[job_id]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[job_name]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[job_execution_id]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[start_time]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[end_time]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[lifecycle]
            --  ,org_job_exe.[last_message]
            --  ,null
            --  ,@activity
            --FROM inserted as org_job_exe

            --BEGIN
            --  SET @activity = 'INSERT';

            --  INSERT INTO [dbo].[custom_status]
            --      ([job_id]
            --     ,[job_name]
            --     ,[job_execution_id]
            --     ,[start_time]
            --     ,[end_time]
            --     ,[lifecycle]
            --     ,[message]
            --     ,[exception]
            --     ,[column_state])
            --  SELECT
            --      org_job_exe.[job_id]
            --      ,(SELECT name
            --      FROM jobs_internal.jobs
            --      WHERE job_id = org_job_exe.job_id)
            --      ,org_job_exe.[job_execution_id]
            --      ,org_job_exe.[start_time]
            --      ,org_job_exe.[end_time]
            --      ,org_job_exe.[lifecycle]
            --      ,(SELECT message
            --      FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
            --      WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
            --      ,(SELECT exception
            --      FROM jobs_internal.job_task_executions
            --      WHERE job_execution_id = org_job_exe.job_execution_id)
            --      ,@activity
            --  FROM inserted as org_job_exe
         --END;
        END;
GO
```

The trigger on the view never fires!
I know little bit of bulk DML operations won't fire triggers.

Is there something wrong with my trigger.

1. The fast trigger if it fires it will block all the other operations on table
2. The second trigger never fires on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the PRINT statements. Long shot but maybe they are causing a hang that stops future processing.

Comment: @Shirz Bhaiji tried it without the PRINT. Didn't work yet